# Is it possible to load an XML file, modify a parameter and then save it as a text file?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a file which is in xml format.

```
  <fciv>
  -<FILE_ENTRY>
  <name>e:\logs3\database1.txt</name>
  <MD5>0rxJSXF5tCO3pAk3IcSJBA==</MD5>
  </FILE_ENTRY>
  </FCIV>
```

I want to load this file using vbscript, and save the "name" and "md5" part to a text file.. is it possible? if yes, how to do it? can I get some help?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254600/reading-xml-file-with-vbscript

Comment: ya that is what I wanna do but how do I save it to a txt file after absorbing the parameters of the xml file???

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5399c99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: the documentation part not helping. its not normal writing to a txt file program. I have to extract info from an xml file and save it to a text using vbs

Comment: Arvind Haran pointed you to an answer covering the extraction part. The documentation covers the writing to a file part. Anything else missing?

Comment: ya I tried using the syntax and logic identical to the syntax used in the link posted mr arvind but even then the program has errors wen running

Comment: WScript.Echo "Port " & port.nodeValue & " has IP address is " & ip.nodeValue                                                          when I use the above line, only the text in the "" is being printed but the values (ie values pointed by port.nodevalue and ip.nodevalue is not printed)

Comment: So, update your question with the code you currently have, and the error(s) it's raising.

Comment: got the answer guys! thanks to both of u! helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

This should do it ...

**script.vbs**

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.Load "input.xml"
Set xmlNodeName = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/FCIV/FILE_ENTRY/name")
Set xmlNodeMD5 = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/FCIV/FILE_ENTRY/MD5")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True)
file.WriteLine "* name: " & xmlNodeName.Text
file.WriteLine "* MD5: " & xmlNodeMD5.Text
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FCIV>
  <FILE_ENTRY>
    <name>e:\logs3\database1.txt</name>
    <MD5>0rxJSXF5tCO3pAk3IcSJBA==</MD5>
  </FILE_ENTRY>
</FCIV>
```

*remark: XML is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe*

**output.txt**

```
* name: e:\logs3\database1.txt
* MD5: 0rxJSXF5tCO3pAk3IcSJBA==
```